# Take n items at random from a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list L and want to return a list of n items from it, at random.

Right now I am relying on itertools.combinations and then picking one at random, but I have to wait a while until the list looks like something that isn't stuck with a lot of items near the start of the list, so it's not really "random."

Comment: Ok.so can you show us your code?

Comment: @Kasra I already explained it. I use itertools.combinations and then (manually) take one at random.

Comment: You can ask another question with your code! then you'll get the desire answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to sample K items from a list of population n.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(100), 5)
[56, 1, 0, 60, 61]
```

Comment: I didn't notice random.sample. Thanks! I can accept in 8.

Comment: @ArukaJ: If this answers your question you may want to accept it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

L=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

a=len(L)
n=5

K=[ L[randint(0,a-1)%a] for x in xrange(0,n)]

print K
```

Sample output

> [6, 4, 3, 2, 5]

Comment: Why `%a`?  [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) returns a value in the range `[a, b]` already.  You should generally never modulo random data.  Furthermore this will generate duplicate results, as you are sapling "with replacement".  Just use [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) as was already suggested; it's easier and faster.